# Recording status transitions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, state-machine

We have a Rails app that has a `Subscription` model with a `status` field that's a string. Values are things like `active`, `canceled`, `dunning`, etc.

We don't record when the `status` transitions from one state to another, but I'd like to. My challenge is thinking about how to be able to easily answer the question:

"What subscriptions were `active` 3 months ago?"

I could make a table like `subscription_status_transitions` with:

- `subscription_id`
- `status`
- `transitioned_at`

In order to answer the question above, it seems like I'd have to get the first `status` that's < date in question (3 months ago)?

Is there a better way to record this kind of thing to easily answer that question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two alternative solutions: event sourcing and temporary tables

With event sourcing you'll record events about state changes and build `Subscription` status basing on event list. To get a historical status, you just query for events until the point in time that interests you. It's quite similar to what you described.

You can also use temporal table and keep timestamps when subscription statues (or the whole subscription) was valid (`valid_to`, `valid_from`). Instead of updating rows, you'll insert a new one and setting a `valid_to` timestamp in the old one. You'll just query for a subsctiption that had `valid_from < $date AND valid_to > $date`. More details on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_database#Bitemporal_relations) - it's a good starter.

Comment: This is great -- some formal approaches to investigate more closely. The latter is new to me. Thanks!

Comment: The latter is a bit similar to concepts used in postgres MVCC